# Format data in blocks

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I use this Angular code to format text into profile page as blocks of data:

```
<div class="element-box">
  <div class="details-wrapper">
    <p><b class="label">Remote IP</b>{{apiattempt.remote_ip}}</p>
    <p><b class="label">Raw Request</b>
      <pre>
        {{apiattempt.raw_request | xmlBeautyfier }}
      </pre>
    <p><b class="label">Raw Response</b>{{apiattempt.raw_response | xmlBeautyfier }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.details-wrapper {
  padding: 20px 0;

  h4 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  .activity {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: .8em;
    color: #9e9e9e;
  }

  p {
    .label {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

But I get this visual result:

[image]

As you can see the XML data is not aligned properly. Is there some way to move it aligned like the rest of the text?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `[innerHTML]` and pass your content in a `pre` tag instead. But you need to make sure it is intended properly.

```
<p><b class="label">Raw Response</b>
  <pre [innerHTML]="apiattempt.raw_response"></pre>
</p>
```

> Text in a  element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.

Comment: What does xmlBeautyfier do? Paste it's code Try passing in the `[innerHTML]="apiattempt.raw_response | xmlBeautyfier"`. Not sure if it works that way

Comment: Try using the method mentioned in the comment.

Comment: I get: ERROR in : Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "p". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("="label">Raw Response</b>
    <pre [innerHTML]="apiattempt.raw_response | xmlBeautyfier"></pre>
    [ERROR ->]</p>

    <p><b class="label">Raw Response</b>{{apiattempt.raw_response | xmlBeautyfier }}</p>